# Different default datetime format in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

We recently moved our database from SQL Server 2005 to 2014. But now we are having an issue with how the server converts `datetime` from `varchar`.

Previously, a date string `2017-06-30` was converted correctly as July 30, but now even with the user and the database with the language set to Spanish, it still converts the date format as `yyyy-dd-MM`.

Is there some way to permanently change the configuration to fit the original one? One work around we found was to add `SET LANGUAGE ymd` at the beginning, but the amount of procedures doesn't make this feasible in a timely manner.

Comment: Use ANSI Standard and your date values will be free of the culture , `YYYYMMDD` is ANSI standard is always treated the same under any culture/language .

Comment: This is due to the default language of the login. Check what it is on both servers.